# Angularjs ui-grid filter complex expression

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

How can I filter a complex expression mapping like "brand.title". Here is my fileds initialization :

```
$scope.gridOptions2.columnDefs = [
    { field: 'code', displayName: "Code" },
    { field: 'brand.title', displayName: "Brand", resizable: true },
];
```

And the filter :

```
$scope.singleFilter = function(renderableRows) {
    var matcher = new RegExp($scope.selectedBrand);
    renderableRows.forEach(function(row) {
        var match = false;
        ['code', 'brand.title' ].forEach(function(field) {
            if (row.entity[field].match(matcher)) {
                match = true;
            }
        });
        if (!match) {
            row.visible = false;
        }
    });
    return renderableRows;
};
```

Filtring on code field works fine but brand.title gives the following error :
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined**

Comment: I have this same issue, is this a known issue with ui-grid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alternative is :

```
$scope.gridOptions2 = {
    columnDefs : [
                  { field: 'code', displayName: "Code", enableFiltering: true },
                  { field: 'brand.title', displayName: "Brand", resizable: true, enableFiltering: true, filter: {
                      term : $scope.term }}
                ],
    onRegisterApi : function(gridApi) {
          $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    }
};

 $scope.singleFilter = function() {
    $scope.gridApi.grid.columns[2].filter.term = $scope.term;
 };
```